# Convolve gives inconsistent results if performed symbolically and numerically

Tags: convolution

**Response from Wolfram Technical Support at end.**

Suppose that I have an instrument response function of the form:

```
response[t_]=0.2583*(1/(E^(0.25*(-2.6 + t))*(1 + 13.5/E^(1.67*(-2.6 + 
             t)))^10.9) + (961*(1 - E^(-0.236*(-2.6 + t))))/
             (E^(1.67*(-2.6 + t))*(1 + 13.5/E^(1.67*(-2.6 + t)))^11.9))
```

This function looks like this:

[image]

I got this function by fitting experimental data where my underlying signal should be a step function, and then taking the derivative of that fit. So the natural thing to do next is to convolve this instrument response function with a step function to verify that I am getting simulated data that matches experiment.

```
instantAddition[t_, t0_, amp_] = amp UnitStep[t - t0];
```

When I try this using fixed values of t0 and amp, it works:

```
simulatedData[t_] = Convolve[instantAddition[x, 50, 3.92], 
                    response[x], x, t];
Plot[simulatedData[t], {t, 0, 200}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image]

But when I try to do the convolution with t0 and amp unspecified (because they should really be fitting parameters), and then plug in those same values that I used above, everything blows up.

```
simulatedData2[t_, t0_, amp_] = Convolve[instantAddition[x, t0, amp], 
                                response[x], x, t];
Plot[simulatedData2[t, 50, 3.92], {t, 0, 200}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image]

What is going on here?

**Edited to add an attempted (and failed) workaround**: So I was worried that the step function was causing the problem, so I tried to replace the step function with a sigmoid that has a much faster rise than my data point spacing, but that broke the first case!

**Edited to add response from Wolfram Technical Support:** This is a machine underflow problem. They provided a workaround, and said that the issue remains under investigation. The workaround is:

```
Plot[Rationalize[simulatedData2[t, 50, 3.92], 0] // Evaluate, 
     {t, 0, 200}, PlotRange -> Full, WorkingPrecision -> 20] // Quiet
```

Comment: Which version of Mathematica are you using?

Comment: This is on 11.3.0.0 on a 64-bit Windows 8.1 system. I also have access to 12.0 on another machine, and will edit this comment with whether I get the same results on that platform as soon as I test it.

Comment: It works fine for me - I got the correct plot with `simulatedData2`.

Comment: When I try it on MMA v. 12, the first version (with the fixed t0 and amp values) breaks.

Comment: @MelaGo: If you remove the semicolon on the simulatedData2 definition, what output do you get?

Comment: A long expression that starts with `0.2583*amp*((7.662163316055585*Hypergeometric2F1[0.14970059880239522, 10.9, 
      1.1497005988023952, -1037.6249571141127/E^(1.67*t)] - 
    7.662163316055585*E^(0.25*t0)*Hypergeometric2F1[0.14970059880239522, 
      10.9, 1.1497005988023952, -1037.6249571141127*
       E^(-1.67*t + 1.67*t0)] + 1.4233572739908889*^-34*E^(18.203*t)*
     Hypergeometric2F1[10.750299401197605, 10.9, 11.750299401197605, 
      -0.0009637393483491793*E^(1.67*t)])/E^(0.25*t) + `...

Comment: @MelaGo: That looks identical to what I get.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is then... because my plot looks fine. I can also plot that long expression with `expr/. {t0 -> 50, amp -> 3.92}` and it also looks the same.

Comment: I have now tried this on three different computers. In all cases, I started fresh Mathematica sessions from a fresh boot, and copy-pasted the code directly from my OP. One machine is Windows 8.1 with MMA 11.3. One is Windows 10 with MMA 11.3. The third is Windows 8.1 with MMA 12.0. All three fail (and the third machine fails the version with fixed t0 and amp in addition to the general case). I would love to hear if anyone else can reproduce this error.

Comment: I am on MMA 9.0, Windows XP.

Comment: Thank you for that info! It therefore looks like this is something that has broken between MMA 9 and MMA 11.3. I have submitted a bug report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply the response by a UnitStep, because it probably is zero for negative time.

```
response[t_] = 
  UnitStep[t] (0.2583*(1/(E^(0.25*(-2.6 + t))*(1 + 
             13.5/E^(1.67*(-2.6 + t)))^10.9) + (961*(1 - 
            E^(-0.236*(-2.6 + t))))/(E^(1.67*(-2.6 + t))*(1 + 
             13.5/E^(1.67*(-2.6 + t)))^11.9)));
```

[image: Convolved Responses]

Comment: That solved it! Thank you!

Comment: @KevinAusman You are welcome!  I'm just glad it worked and I didn't have to go old school and go the Fourier transform route. Thank you for the accept.

Comment: Unfortunately, the fix you found for this problem didn't help when I tried to apply it to more realistic data. I think the issue is distinct, so I have started a new question about it: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/198985/getting-convolve-to-behave-in-preparation-for-nonlinearmodelfit